# null handling in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Stored Procedure is like below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIRSTPROC (ID1 IN VARHAR2, ID2 OUT NUMBER )
AS 

BEGIN
 SELECT id2val INTO ID2
 FROM 
 WHERE id1val = ID1;
END
```

If i am passing

if i pass valid value then i am getting the output.

ID1 := 5;

ID1 as NULL  VALUE I AM GETTING run time ERROR in the SELECT statement. Please note my table contains NULL values also. How to handle this condition.

ID1 := null;
 calling the procedure

Please let me know what changes i need to make?

Comment: You need a table name in your `FROM` clause.

Comment: You should use the `nvl` function.

Comment: With same query, i do see many questions wavering over here!

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is not equal to `NULL`.  So when you are passing in `NULL`, and doing a query using only an equality condition, you can't get a match.  So I assume you are getting a no-data-found exception (P.S. instead of saying you are getting "an error" it can be helpful to say specifically what error you are getting).

You have to handle `NULL` explicitly.

```
SELECT id2val INTO id2
FROM whatever
WHERE ( id1val = id1 OR (id1val IS NULL AND id1 IS NULL) )
```

Another possibility is to use a condition like `NVL( id1val, -1 ) = NVL( id1, -1 )`, where `-1` is some value that will never actually occur in your data. But this is dependent on choosing a good sentinel value, and can impact the effectiveness of indexes on the query.

Note that if your table contains multiple rows with `NULL` values for `ID1VAL`, this query will then raise too-many-rows.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is not equals to `NULL`, but you can use the [nvl](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php) function to fix your equality like this

```
WHERE nvl(id1val, 'na')=nvl(id1, 'na')
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing whether a `NULL` value is equal to another value (including another `NULL`) will always return false. Instead you can compare if the two values are equal or if the first value `IS NULL` and the second value `IS NULL`.

Amending [my previous answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712878/oracle-stored-procedure-inout-parameter-issue-got-the-solution-typo-error):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIRSTPROC (
  ID1 IN  table_name.id1val%TYPE,
  ID2 OUT table_name.id2val%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT id2val
  INTO   ID2
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  ( id1val = ID1 OR ( ID1 IS NULL AND id1val IS NULL ) );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    ID2 := NULL;
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    ID2 := NULL;
END;
/
```